# Symbian app on Python note usage

Tags: python, symbian, pys60

When I try to use this command

```
appuifw.note(u"Connecting to %s" % (address), "conf");
```

I'm getting error: "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mentioned arise in cases like

```
>>> print "my name is %s" %('foo','bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

It means I have 2 values to replace `('foo', 'bar')` but only provided `one` place holder `(%s)`.

To correct it

```
>>> print "my name is %s %s" %('foo','bar')
    my name is foo bar
```

There is also a another way to achieve this using [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
>>> print "my name is {0} {1}".format('foo','bar')
    my name is foo bar
```

Comment: `str.format` has been added in Python 2.6. I think PyS60 is still on 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option with dictionaries

```
mydict = {'foo': 'bar', 'foo2': 'bar2'}
print "my name is %(foo)s" % mydict
```

this way you can use only foo if you want.

Note the last 's' is for 'string', so if you add something like %(foo)d it means %d with name foo.